# Получение данных из балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть балун:

```
var MyBalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div class="main">'+
        '<div class="driverInfo driverInfoContent" id="header">'+
        '<div class="photo driverInfoContent"><img src="icons/avatar.jpg" class="avatar"></div>'+
        '<div class="name driverInfoContent"><p>Ivan Ivan</p></div>'+
        '<div class="rating driverInfoContent"><p>4.8</p></div>'+
        '<div class="ratingPic driverInfoContent"><img src="icons/ratingIcon.png" class="ratingPic"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="line" id="footer">'+
        '<div class="carInfo line">'+
        '<div class="carPic"><img src="icons/Taxi_1.png" class="carPicture"></div>'+
        '<div class="carModelNumber">'+
        '<div class="model">BMX x4</div>'+
        '<div class="number">1234 BM-4</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="reqBtn line btnPic" id="coords" onclick="hide()"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="afterHide" id="afterHide" hidden>'+
        '<input type="text" class="input" id="suggest" placeholder="Введите адресс">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="buttons" hidden>'+
        '<div class="cancelBtn cancelBtnPic" id="cancel" onclick="back()" hidden></div>'+
        '<div class="confirmBtn confirmBtnPic" id="confirm"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
       '</div>'
    );
```

Он открывается при нажатию на метки, которые берутся из json файла.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.678703,
          23.835601
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Pizza&Coffe"
      },
      "options":{
        "preset":"islands#blueHomeIcon",
        "hasBalloon": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.674244,
          23.737227
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Казановского 11"
      },
      "status": "free"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.682719,
          23.831406
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Виленская 6"
      },
      "status": "free"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 3,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.656318,
          23.849840
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Янки Купалы 80/2"
      },
      "status": "busy"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 4,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.622756,
          23.814832
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Великая Ольшанка 15"
      },
      "status": "busy"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 5,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          53.685108,
          23.839967
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Ожешко 22"
      },
      "status": "free"
    }
  ]
}
```

В балуне есть поле `input`. Я хочу вводить в это поле адрес и строить маршрут к этому адресу. Проблема в том, что js не видит этот `input`, т.к. он создается в js файле и не относится к родительскому HTML документу.

Как мне его туда добавить? Бьюсь уже 3 день.

Весь код js-файла.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [53.677850, 23.829484],
            zoom: 10,
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    var MyBalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div class="main">'+
        '<div class="driverInfo driverInfoContent" id="header">'+
        '<div class="photo driverInfoContent"><img src="icons/avatar.jpg" class="avatar"></div>'+
        '<div class="name driverInfoContent"><p>Ivan Ivan</p></div>'+
        '<div class="rating driverInfoContent"><p>4.8</p></div>'+
        '<div class="ratingPic driverInfoContent"><img src="icons/ratingIcon.png" class="ratingPic"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="line" id="footer">'+
        '<div class="carInfo line">'+
        '<div class="carPic"><img src="icons/Taxi_1.png" class="carPicture"></div>'+
        '<div class="carModelNumber">'+
        '<div class="model">BMX x4</div>'+
        '<div class="number">1234 BM-4</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="reqBtn line btnPic" id="coords" onclick="hide()"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="afterHide" id="afterHide" hidden>'+
        '<input type="text" class="input" id="suggest" placeholder="Введите адресс">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="buttons" hidden>'+
        '<div class="cancelBtn cancelBtnPic" id="cancel" onclick="back()" hidden></div>'+
        '<div class="confirmBtn confirmBtnPic" id="confirm"></div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'
    );

    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: false,
        gridSize: 32,
        geoObjectBalloonLayout: MyBalloonContentLayout,
        geoObjectBalloonShadow: false,
        geoObjectBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
        geoObjectBalloonOffset: [-285, -155],
        geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
    });
    objectManager1 = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: false,
        gridSize: 32,
        hasBalloon:false
    });
    objectManager2 = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: false,
        gridSize: 32,
        hasBalloon:false
    });
    myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
        myMap.balloon.close();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function (data) {

        for(let i=1;i<data["features"].length;i++){
            objectManager2.add(data["features"][0]);
            if (data["features"][i]["status"]==="free"){
                data["features"][i]['options'] = [];
                data["features"][i]['options']['preset'] = 'islands#greenAutoIcon';
                objectManager.add(data["features"][i])
            }else{
                data["features"][i]['options'] = [];
                data["features"][i]['options']['preset'] = 'islands#redAutoIcon';
                data["features"][i]['options']['hasBalloon'] = 'false';
                objectManager1.add(data["features"][i])
            }
        }
        console.log(data);
        var maxLat = 0,
            maxLon = 0,
            minLat = 100,
            minLon = 100;
        objectManager.objects.each(function (object) {
            var lat = object.geometry.coordinates[0],
                lon = object.geometry.coordinates[1];
            maxLat = (lat <= maxLat) ? maxLat : lat;
            maxLon = (lon <= maxLon) ? maxLon : lon;
            minLat = (lat >= minLat) ? minLat : lat;
            minLon = (lon >= minLon) ? minLon : lon;
        }, myMap);
        objectManager1.objects.each(function (object) {
            var lat = object.geometry.coordinates[0],
                lon = object.geometry.coordinates[1];
            maxLat = (lat <= maxLat) ? maxLat : lat;
            maxLon = (lon <= maxLon) ? maxLon : lon;
            minLat = (lat >= minLat) ? minLat : lat;
            minLon = (lon >= minLon) ? minLon : lon;
        }, myMap);
        myMap.setBounds([[minLat, minLon], [maxLat, maxLon]]);
    });
    myMap.balloon.close(false);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager1);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager2);
}
```

Comment: а почему хотите именно через балун это делать? можно добавить на карту [собственный элемент управления](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control?from=SO), показывать его при клике на метку и заполнять нужными деталями. Если обязательно делать это через балуны, то вам нужно переопределять метод build и вообще заморачиваться с его логикой, которая вроде и не нужна задаче.

Comment: Требуется именно через балун. Я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите, как сделано [в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout?from=SO) и прочитайте [документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/templateLayoutFactory-docpage/?from=SO) - вам нужно переопределять метод build, без этого это просто "мёртвый" html. После приведите код, если что-то не получится.

Answer (score 1):

При создании html шаблона надо переопределить метод build. В этом методе можно получить доступ к корневому элементу используя метод getElement. Пример:

```
var MyBalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  `
   <div class="main">
     <input name="myinput"/>
   </div>
  `,
  {
    build: function () {
      MyBalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
      var input = this.getElement().querySelector('input[name=myinput]');
      console.log('input', input);

    }
  }
);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdswokty/13/

Comment: И потом обращаться к переменной, хранящей в себе инпут, а не по Id этого инупута, я правильно вас понимаю?

Comment: Организация кода на ваше усмотрение остается