# Обработка события появления балуна Яндекс Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, которая описана [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869390/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Код вывода балуна с его содержимым по двойному клику:

```
myMap.events.add('dblclick', function(e) {
    if (!myMap.balloon.isOpen()) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');
        myMap.balloon.open(coords, {
            //здесь доработать код вывода формы ввода
            contentBody: '<div id="forma"><div id="forma_list"><h3>Добавление вида муравьев</h3><select id="rod" ></select><br /><select id="vid"></select><br /></div><p id="cap">капча</p><div id="childrenContainer"></div><br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button></div>'
        });
    } else {
        myMap.balloon.close();
    }
 });
```

2 дня мучаюсь над тем, чтобы отследить событие, когда select-ы балуна станут видимым для js функции (чтобы реализовать работу зависимых списков).
Если я вставляю функцию в обработчик появления балуна, напимер вот так:

```
myMap.events.add('dblclick', function(e) {
    if (!myMap.balloon.isOpen()) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');
        myMap.balloon.open(coords, {
            //здесь доработать код вывода формы ввода
            contentBody: '<div id="forma"><div id="forma_list"><h3>Добавление вида муравьев</h3><select id="rod" ></select><br /><select id="vid"></select><br /></div><p id="cap">капча</p><div id="childrenContainer"></div><br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button></div>'
        });
        myfunc(); //моя функция
    } else {
        myMap.balloon.close();
    }
 });
```

то моя функция стартует быстрее, чем объекты на нём становятся видимы для этой функции. В итоге селекты не обрабатываются.

Пробовал различные уловки,аля:

```
$("#rod").on("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) { 
 //запуск обработки селектов
}
```

Ничего не помогает (не видит появление балуна), ну или не туда вставлял код. Неужели нужно городить забор, и переписывать весь код, только потому что нет способа отловить доступность объектов. Или есть, да я не так хорошо знаю JS.

Помогите, отловить момент, когда dom-объекты балуна станут доступными для моей функции. Maps Api не так хорошо знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Метод balloon.open https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.Balloon-docpage/ является асинхронным и возвращает промис. Если что-то нужно сделать после того как балун появится на карте, то это нужно делать в функции-обработчике для объекта-promise. Вот так должно работать:

```
myMap.balloon.open(coords, {
        //здесь доработать код вывода формы ввода
        contentBody: '<div id="forma"><div id="forma_list"><h3>Добавление вида муравьев</h3><select id="rod" ></select><br /><select id="vid"></select><br /></div><p id="cap">капча</p><div id="childrenContainer"></div><br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Сохранить</button></div>'
    }).then(myfunc)
```

Comment: Почистил кеш, и код перестал работать. Функция действительно вызывается 1 раз, но почему-то всё равно раньше, чем становятся доступными инпуты на балуне :(

Comment: Добавьте пример в котором видно проблему, пожалуйста. Можно на jsfiddle.